# Deleting SharePoint files via Excel

Tags: sharepoint-addin, excel, delete

At work we have a spreadsheet of accounts that after a certain amount of time need to be deleted. So far the only way we have to do this is by manually going through each and every account and hitting delete in Sharepoint. When several hundred folders in SharePoint need to be deleted at a time this can be incredibly time consuming. What I want to know how to do is to link the spreadsheet to SharePoint and find a way to automate this process. Any ideas and aid would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can automate it using powershell.

Place the spreadsheet in a well known location and create a Scheduled Task on a (SharePoint)server. Then use powershell to read/parse the Excel file (or an CSV-export of the said file) and loop over all records. In the PowerShell script you can use the SharePoint Object Model to delete the users from SharePoint.

(Mind you, reading CSV in powershell is simpler than reading an Excelfile).

Other option is to ditch the excelfile all togehter and use a SharePoint list as basis. Loop over all items in this list using powershell and perform your desired action(s).